# store in blob storage from queue trigger

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

This question is edited as I did not have a good idea about how binding works in azure functions and the my question was poorly formed.

basically, I wanted to know how to write store a blob to a blog storage which has to be triggered by a queue msg (meaning the blob should be created in an azure queue trigger and then stored to a blob storage).

Tom Sun has given the answer which I was expecting

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] and people will be able to help you, and understand where you are having problems.

Comment: im trying to queue a message to the queue storage which will recieve a json string. i need to write that string to a text file and once all the lines are writted to the text file i must store the text file in the blob storage at the end of the queue trigger. sorry buddy, i dodnt have codes to show you as an example

Comment: Edit your question with an example of what you have done.

Comment: [FunctionName("ReportFunc")]
        [return: Queue("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        public static string Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"Report Test: {myQueueItem}");

            if (myQueueItem.Length > 11)
            {
                var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(myQueueItem);
            }

            return "return test";

        }
    }

Comment: @NathanMcCoy, please help bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store the queue messages to an azure blob via queue trigger, you could use the cloudAppendblob. The following the demo code

```
[FunctionName("TestQueueTrigger")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("queueName", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem,TraceWriter log)
{

   log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureWebJobsStorage"));
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
   container.CreateIfNotExists();

   var appendBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference("blobName.txt");

   if (!appendBlob.Exists())
   {
        appendBlob.CreateOrReplace();
        appendBlob.AppendText(myQueueItem);
   }
   else
   {
      appendBlob.AppendText($",{myQueueItem}");
   }


 }
```